# Need help returning points based on checking a letter of a string

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to check if the string has a letter based on the given test case. However, the letter *a* has an exception, each letter of a will be counted as half is value. For example, the letter *a* is worth 300, but we want to divide by 2, and each letter will be worth 150 points instead.

**UnitTest:**

```
[TestCase("software", 'w', 250, 250)]
[TestCase("craftmanship", 'a', 300, 300)]
public void WheelofFortune(string secretWord, char letterGuess, int pointValue, int expected)
    {
        var actual = warmups.WheelofFortune(secretWord, letterGuess, pointValue);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

**Unit:**

```
//Given a target word, a letter guess by a customer, and a point value. 
//Return the number of points earned.

    public int WheelofFortune(string secretWord, char letterGuess, int pointValue)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int pointValue2 = (pointValue / 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess)
                sum += pointValue;

            if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess && letterGuess == 'a')
                sum += pointValue2;

            if (secretWord[i] == secretWord.Length - 1)
                return sum;
        }
        return sum;            
    }
```

The problem is on craftmanship: 
Message:   Expected: 300
But was:  900

Why am I getting 900 and not 300?

Comment: By the way, `if (secretWord[i] == secretWord.Length - 1)` doesn't make much sense to me. You're not even checking the position here, you're checking if the character code of the character at position `i` (e.g. A is ASCII code 65) is equal to the length of the word -1. If you intended `i == secretWord.Length - 1`, then this is unnecessary since your loop continuation condition will exit at the end of the word anyway.

Comment: Check the new edited version of my response, first one use the switch case, second one use the Dictionary to make it much more flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens since your logic is incorrect on simple debugging it suggests, when you find letter `a`, then both the logic executes and thus instead of **150** per iteration your value becomes **450** and thus **450*2 = 900**:

```
if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess)
                sum += pointValue;

 if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess && letterGuess == 'a')
                sum += pointValue2;
```

**Fix 1 using a Switch-Case:**

```
public int WheelofFortune(string secretWord, char letterGuess, int pointValue)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.Length; i++)
    {
        switch(secretWord[i])
        {
            case 'a':
                sum += pointValue/2;
            break;
            default:
                if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess)
                  sum += pointValue;
            break;          
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**Fix 2: A better design, using Dictionary** (Just add another key to dictionary and it will calculate as per new logic automatically)

```
public static Dictionary<char,double> sampleData = new Dictionary<char, double>
{
    ['a'] = 0.5
};

public int WheelofFortune(string secretWord, char letterGuess, int pointValue)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.Length; i++)
        if(sampleData.ContainsKey(secretWord[i]))
            sum += (int)(pointValue * sampleData[letterGuess]);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `secretWord[i]` comparison to the string length is not correct, it shall be just `i`,  ideally whole string length comparison logic is redundant, and shall be removed as in my second solution, since you anyway return `sum` in the end

Answer (score 3):

Ben and Mrinal have shown you the immediate prolem in the code.  I'm going to focus more on the structure of the code.

From your question it sounds like you want something like this:

> Given a word, a guess character and a score, multiply the score by number of matching
>   characters.  If the guess character is `'a'` then it scores half.

In that case the code can be greatly simplified to:

```
public int WheelofFortune(string secretWord, char letterGuess, int pointValue)
{
    int count = secretWord.Count(letter => letter == letterGuess);
    int sum = pointValue * count;
    if (letterGuess == 'a')
        sum /= 2;
    return sum;
}
```

This gives the values that you are testing for, abstracts out the loop and reads a lot more like the description.  It also simplifies the logic to the point where you are less likely to miss something like the double-match.

Not sure why your code includes a test for the character being equal to the length of the string less one, since that doesn't appear to be relevant to the question.  Happy to correct if that's needed.

Comment: Quite a neat response @Corey, +1, in my view though we shall avoid the `If-else`, since any further modification would make the code complex, please check the my modified responses, one using `switch case` and other one using `Dictionary`, they would make the future extensions much simpler

Answer (score 0):

You're doing both `if` clauses, so:

```
if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess)
            sum += pointValue;
```

You match `a` twice so you add 2x300 = 600 to the sum. Then

```
if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess && letterGuess == 'a')
            sum += pointValue2;
```

This also matches, so you add 2*150 = 300 to the sum.
600 + 300 = 900.

You need to either use `if else` or a case statement. So something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.Length; i++)
    {
        if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess && letterGuess == 'a')
        {
            sum += pointValue2;
        }
        else if (secretWord[i] == letterGuess)
        {
            sum += pointValue;
        }
        //if (secretWord[i] == secretWord.Length - 1)
        //{
        //    return sum;
        //}

    }
```

This way once one `if` clause is satisfied it ignores the rest.

Comment: This doesn't handles a corner case since you have shifted the `return sum` to the top, if the last letter also is `letterguess`, then it's points will not be added. In OP's program return is in the end post adding the sum for all letters irrespective of the position, please fix the corner case

Comment: I assumed there was some rule regarding the last letter, otherwise it didn't really make sense to have that return clause at all. Original code already returns sum after the last letter is processed anyway.

Comment: It doesn't match the last character, it matches a character whose code value is the length of the string.  Seems like a mistake to me, definitely not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes missed out that part it shall be just `i` not the character `secretword[i]`, though code as such doesn't makes sense but it compiles since char ascii value is compared in the logic

Comment: @Ben your response will anyway have an issue if the corner case is not handled, yes code logic doesn't looks correct, but that's different discussion altogether

Comment: I edited my answer so it should work the way it looks like the original code was intended to work.

Comment: @Ben You forgot to remove the initial `else` :)